# binding data to control wpf error

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to learn WPF and how to connect and bind a sql database I have so i can return information etc.  I have connected the database, the dataset is within solution explorer, the data sources are there for selection and there is a .edmx file within solution explorer.

I am trying to drag a table across from the data sources to the main window in the mainWindow.xaml page.  I am getting this error.  Can anyone advise on what I have to do.

"Cannot add the control to the design surface or bind to the control because the type wpftryout.CiaranTestDataSet cannot be resolved.  Please try to build the project or add necessary assembly references."

Comment: seems like you are missing some dependencies for the control.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, There is no direct way to include SQL Database object for Display purpose. What you can do is get information from database in one table and then you can bind your information to specific object  As mentioned in below link

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/362436/Data-binding-in-WPF-DataGrid-control

In case u required more help, Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After reading [this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9fc4f835-d6c0-4d04-86c2-779c1f8e0791/unable-to-drag-data-source-to-control-to-bind](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9fc4f835-d6c0-4d04-86c2-779c1f8e0791/unable-to-drag-data-source-to-control-to-bind) I created a new project on my C: drive (rather than the network location VS defaulted to) and it suddenly worked fine!